# How to slow down a P Channel MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet

I built the following schematic on a breadboard with the goals:

1. If the voltage is applied on the source of the P Channel MOSFET, the MOSFET must not conduct. (It may conduct for a short time, but eventually it shall disconnect the source from the drain.)
2. If the voltage is applied on the drain of the P Channel MOSFET, the MOSFET shall conduct.

The voltage sources are a voltage regulator (on the drain side), and an unregulated 3V3 source (on the source side). Only one voltage will be connected at any given time and: it won't change while the device is on.

The goal is to disconnect the voltage regulator completely, when there is an unregulated 3V3 source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJPS2y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now comes the problem:
On the breadboard this schematic is working as expected.
But on a fabricated PCB the Gate of the MOSFET always stays low when the 3V3 source is connected (Output of the Comparator = low).
The main difference between the breadboard design and the PCB design is: I'm using a different MOSFET. On the breadboard I'm using an Infineon IPP45P03P4L, on the PCB a Vishay SI2305.

My suspicion: Timing.
The comparator has a typical 4us propagation delay.
The MOSFET has a ~20ns turn on delay time.
So I guess at startup the MOSFET conducts almost instantly since its gate is at 0V and the comparator has not output anything yet?

Therefore my question:
How can I make the MOSFET startup slower without adding any resistor/diode on the drain/source side since this is the power rail?

My second question:
Why does this setup work on the breadboard?
The main difference is the capacitance of the MOSFET (Infineon vs Vishay) - the Vishay (not working) has a lower capacitance than the Infineon (working)...

Comment: ˙ǝɔᴉu s,ʇɐɥ┴ ˙ʎʞs ǝɥʇ oʇ dn ƃuᴉʇuᴉod punoɹפ

Comment: Your circuit makes no sense. First you have not shown the other 3.3V source.. Second it looks like you are not understanding how a P-Channel works. You need to pull the gate low to turn it on. So your +- connections are backwards on the op-amp. However, even if you correct that, when the MOSFET turns on, the voltage on the sensing pin of the op-amp will go to 3.3V, which will cause the op-amp to try to turn off again. Ultimately it is just going to go into linear mode and hold C1 at whatever voltage that divider is set to.How you ever got this to work on the bread-board.. I have no idea.

Comment: @Trevor: No, it won't go linear, because the overall feedback is positive, not negative. It will simply latch "on", with the opamp output low and the MOSFET drain high, as the OP has discovered.

Comment: @DaveTweed yup, I meant if he inverts the inputs. Circuit makes no sense as drawn.

Comment: Where does the opamp power come from?

Comment: @Trevor: Actually, it does. The other power source (the output of a regulator) is connected directly to the MOSFET drain. If that goes high, he wants the MOSFET to turn on (bypassing the internal body diode).

Comment: @DaveTweed OH... the output is on the left.... sigh... ok that makes more sense...

Comment: Dave Tweed, yes you got me right: the output of the regulator is directly connected to the MOSFET drain. And yes - the idea is to bypass the bode diode when turning the FET on.
The Comparator power comes from the 3V3 line, that is, it is connected to the source of the MOSFET.

Comment: @HansZimmer See my updated answer...

Comment: It is senseless to use Infineon's "world's lowest RdsOn PFET rated for 30V" in a circuit which cannot even handle a 1MOhm bias load on the regulator. Also the Vishay part has very low RdsOn with extremely low Vgs(th)=-0.4~-0.8V while the TL081 saturates with enough voltage to keep it ON when it should be OFF.  Move to delete this question and any future similar design questions until Hans studies more designs to figure how parts work and why designs fail.

Comment: What you're looking for is a so-called *ideal diode*. Google results should lead you down a better path. Usually it's a single IC + an external mosfet. Quite foolproof with a dedicated chip. Discrete solutions will need to add some protection or else it won't be very robust, even assuming it fulfilled its primary function of being a diode.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear, but I think the fix is to put a resistor (~100k) between the MOSFET drain and C1, and another one (~1M) across C1. Together, they make sure that C1 starts out discharged and stays that way through the startup transient, keeping the opamp output high.

BTW, if you want a comparator, you should use a comparator, not an opamp. Opamps generally have very poor performance (and sometimes surprising behaviors) when driven into saturation.

Comment: Maybe... issue is if the gate is pulled low briefly, at power on, the mosfet will turn on, after that it will stay on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The problem is: I can't put a resistor on the source or the drain of the MOSFET. It is the power line for the actual load.

Answer (score 1):

OK now I see the schematic is drawn backwards.

The issue here is your startup condition will pull the gate low on the MOSFET as the opamp starts up. That will turn on the MOSFET when the power is applied on the left. That of course pulls the negative pin of the opamp high keeping the MOSFET on.

As such you need to use the actual voltage delta across the MOSFET to control the gate, not some division of the rail.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKmlxi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note if you are using an op-amp for this it needs to be able to handle rail to rail inputs and drive all the way to the rails.

Fortunately, your rework is easy. Remove R2 and short out R1.

**BTW:** This "ideal diode" circuit is commonly done using [a transistor circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/344993/ideal-diode-pnp-emitter-base-breakdown-voltage-question-pmosfet/345025#345025) that does not require the power supply to operate.

[image]
<sub>(source: [birds-are-nice.me](https://birds-are-nice.me/ipfs/QmSYsdRafbq19UzocGmWnkt9Gn3CuZga2TXvDKXFGQtJvw/piode.png))</sub>

Comment: This is an interesting answer. In fact I had also tested your suggestion on the breadboard (it worked).
But what is the voltage difference across the MOSFET?
If on the source side 3.3V is applied, the difference is 3.3V - making the MOSFET not conduct.
If on the drain side 3.3V is applied, the difference is -0.7V - making the MOSFET conduct.

Does timing not play a role here? Initially the opamp won't output anything, will it? Because it has not started up yet.

Comment: @HansZimmer You see this schematic? This is what I encouraged you to make.

Comment: @HansZimmer, Initially, at power on, the output of the op-amp will be ground. If only the 3.3V unreg is applied the voltage will be minus across the MOSFET so it stays off. If the 3.3V reg is applied initially the voltage across the MOSFET is the diode drop in the regulator, then it turns on and the drop is whatever your current is times the on-resistance. Still positive, still turned on. If you happen to attach both supplies... the MOSFET will turn on if the regulated supply is higher... which should be avoided.

Comment: @HarrySvensson note my drawing is the "right" way around.. Your's had the output on the left.

Comment: @Trevor "*Your's had the output on the left.*" - Well, I can't be perfect, can I? - Jokes aside, I try to put them to the right side, but sometimes it just *looks* better to have it to the left. As long as Vdd = at the top, GND at the bottom, and wires that doesn't look like a cat has played with it, then I'm OK.

Comment: @HarrySvensson indeed. but it sure had me confused :) I thought I'd better mention mine was tother way around in case it confused the OP....

Comment: @Trevor Which design are you talking about specifically?

Comment: @HarrySvensson the OPs original, I was assuming the output voltage was on the right... and circuit made no sense that way.. My bad for making an assumption I guess. MOSFET in reverse mode didn't help..

Comment: @Trevor I tried it out now. I removed R2 and replaced R1 by a 150 Ohm resistor (the lowest value I had). Mosfet conducts.
Then I removed R1 and made a solder bridge. Mosfet still conducts when powered via unregulated 3V3 rail.

Comment: @HansZimmer that may be because the opamp cant drive high enough. Whats the voltage on the gate.

Comment: @Trevor Aaah, now I see, you were talking about Hans's circuit, not one of mine in some other answer. Got it. Ciao.

Comment: @HarrySvensson ah right, I guess I miss-addressed a comment to the wrong H.. oops.. as you were ;)

Comment: @Trevor Voltage @ Gate = 0V. Voltage @ Source and Drain = 3.295V.
My comparator supports rail-to-rail of course, both input and output.

Comment: @HansZimmer if its 3.295V then something else is wrong with your wiring. OPamp V-Out should be close to 3.295 too. Check the voltages on the + - pins.

Comment: @HansZimmer though a pulldown on the left of the mosfet might be a good addition.

Comment: Both V+/V- of the Comparator @ 3,295V

Comment: I guess the following is happening:
V+ sees 3,3V, MOSFET Source sees 3,3V, Mosfet starts to conduct after 20 ns, MOSFET Drain is then @3,3V, then V- sees 3,3V
After 4000 ns Comparator sets its output (to 0V). But at that time the Mosfet is already conducting for ~3900ns.

Comment: @HansZimmer ya, with the other side floating it's going to be unpredictable. whether that is an issue of not.... I cant tell you

Comment: @HansZimmer if you load it down it should shut off though.